# How Importing Images with Labels using addImageToMediaGallery in magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, import, product-images, programmatically

**Magento2.1.x**

I had a problem adding a product **Image Label** programatically. Here's the code I used:

```
    $imageLabel1 = 'Test1';
    $imageLabel2 = 'Test2';
    $imageLabel3 = 'Test3';
    $product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ())) 
            ->addImageToMediaGallery('/test1.jpg', array('image'), false, false);
            ->addImageToMediaGallery('/test2.jpg', array('thumbnail'), false, false);
            ->addImageToMediaGallery('/test3.jpg', array('small_image'), false, false);
```

Where i can set **$imageLabel1 - 2 - 3**?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$imageLabel1 = 'Test1';
$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
    $entry->setLabel($imageLabel1);
}
$product->setStoreId(0);
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
```

## UPDATED

The code above is the only way to set label for a media gallery entry, because there's no direct API from Product to set them.

It also means, you still using your current code to set new media gallery, then use the code above to update label for it after $product->save() (another mean, you have to save() product twice)

Pseudo code

```
public function addImageToMediaGallery(Product $product) {
    // your code
    $product->save();
}

public function updateImageLabel(Product $product, $label) {
    // my code
    $product->save();
}

public function updateProduct() {
    // ....

    $this->addImageToMediaGallery($product);
    foreach ($labels as $label) {
        $this->updateImageLabel($label);
    }

    // ....
}
```

Comment: Thanx, but where can I set this code? I mean below my code? Is it working with multiple image set? see my updated question@ Toan

Comment: @Magento2Devloper I updated my question. Hope it makes more sense to you now :)

Comment: It's working but image label not set image wise. ex - test1.jpg in set imageLabel3. any idea regarding this?

Comment: @Magento2Devloper I don't understand what you mean. Can you update it in your question again?

Comment: I need to set image label like ex - test1.jpg in set 'Test1' Label. in your code set test1.jpg in 'Test3' label.  now understand?

Comment: If you understand the pseudo code I posted then it's pretty easy to do so.... Because I'm passing `$label` into `updateImageLabel()` and there is a `foreach()` to get label from `$labels` (array)

Comment: it's not working anymore.